# how to set password on PDF file using ITextSharp without downloading that PDF File?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, encryption

i create a simple PDF creator application using ASP.NET. that application will create a PDF file on the fly with the password for securing that document. here's my code:

```
    Sub createPDFFile()
        Dim doc As Document = New Document
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + _
                              "pdf\result.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        doc.Open()
        doc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World!! only Testing"))
        doc.Close()
        SetPDFPassword(Server.MapPath("~/pdf/result.pdf"), "resultwithpassword.pdf", "12345")
        Response.Redirect("pdf/1.pdf")
    End Sub
```

and here's my code for add a password to the PDF file:

```
     Private Sub SetPDFPassword(ByVal FullPathPdfFileName As String, ByVal DownloadPDFFileName As String, ByVal ForOpenPassword As String)
        Dim sname As String = FullPathPdfFileName
        Dim sname1 As String = New System.IO.FileInfo(FullPathPdfFileName).DirectoryName & "/test.pdf"
        Dim reader As New PdfReader(sname)
        Dim n As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages

        Dim document As New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New IO.FileStream(sname1, IO.FileMode.Create))
        writer.SetEncryption(PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, ForOpenPassword, Nothing, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting)
        document.Open()
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        Dim page As PdfImportedPage
        Dim rotation As Integer
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < n
            i += 1
            document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
            document.NewPage()
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i)
            rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i)
            If rotation = 90 OrElse rotation = 270 Then
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, _
                reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
            Else
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, _
                0)

            End If
        End While

        document.Close()
        writer.Close()

        Dim PDFfile As New IO.FileStream(sname1, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim FileSize As Long
        FileSize = PDFfile.Length
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(FileSize) - 1) {}
        PDFfile.Read(buffer, 0, CInt(FileSize))
        PDFfile.Close()
        System.IO.File.Delete(sname1)
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & DownloadPDFFileName)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()

    End Sub
```

that code is works perfectly. it can generate a PDF file and add some password to open, but the PDF file will be send to the user. has anyone know how to generate a PDF file with password but that result file still on the server and only can be shown from web browser (not showing a download prompt)?? thanks in advance.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that it is up to the browser to show the pdf in the browser or ask you if you want to download it.

`Adobe Acrobat plug in` can be downloaded at http://www.adobe.com/ and is a plug in to help the user display the pdf in the browser.

How to display the pdf in the broswer with the plugin installed: http://www.okanagan.bc.ca/administration/itservices/edtech/elearn/Configuring_the_browser_to_show_pdf_files.html